# Concatenating strings in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, vb6, string-concatenation

I'm maintaining an application written in Microsoft Access with VBA.

I'm glancing over my code and have just noticed I have subconsciously been concatenating strings together with the plus (+) symbol instead of the ampersand. It's been a few years since I've coded in VB6. Could this cause any issues?

Everything seems fine and it will only take a few minutes to fix, I'm just curious as to whether I'm technically doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ampersand is explicitly a string operation, while the plus is overloaded:

```
Dim num1 As Integer
num1 = RandomNumberBetween(1, 9)

Dim num2 As Integer
num2 = RandomNumberBetween(1, 9)

Dim randomAge As String 'trying to get a random age between 11 and 99

' works
randomDate = "Your age is " & num1 & num2 

'broken
randomDate = "Your age is " + num1 + num2
```

When used with numbers the plus sign will add.

Comment: It gets even more chancy when you have a null with plus.

Comment: Good point, appending a string to a null with the ampersand safely results in a value that is just that string

Answer (score 4):

Some examples, from the VBA immediate window (the difference between the third and fourth is particularly vexing):

```
Print "5" & 6
56

Print 5 & 6
56

Print "5" + 6
 11 

Print "5" + "6"
56 

Print "Five" & 6
Five6

Print "Five" + 6 'Type mismatch

Print "5" & Null
5

Print "5" + Null
Null
```

Answer (score 1):

This can cause issues.

If you use the plus or ampersand to concatenate string values the results are identical

If you use a plus to concatenate a string with a non string value it will throw an error

If you use an ampersand sign vba will try to 'stringify' the values before concatenating.

So `string_value + int_value + date_value` will error and `string_value & int_value & date_value` works fine

Comment: Your example is (partly) correct, but the sentences above it are backwards.  If you use ampersand to concatenate a string with a non-string value, the non-string value is converted to a string and concatenated.  If you use plus, you get an error, unless the string value is numeric, in which case it is converted to a number, and the values are added.  Also, if you use plus and one of the operands is null, the result is null; this doesn't happen with amepersand.

Comment: Thanks I fixed the swapped sentences to eliminate any confusion.