# How to write a query that uses a number as parameter and number type field?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to start a query to retrieve data from Access database using VBA which I want to use a variable number as a parameter. Is it possible?

like the:

```
field name: NMT field type (number)
table name: Orders
```

and the code is like the following:

```vb
Dim Con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim X as Integer
X = me.textbox1.value
Con.Open "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & U.Database01 & "\DB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Rs.Open "select * from Orders where nmt = '" + X + "'", Con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
```

Whenever I run this query, I get a run-time error '13' type mismatch.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use `&` to concatenate, not `+`.

Comment: Also, you could look at using parameters also  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters

Comment: Your query is trying to compare a number field type to a string.  Remove the single quotes.

Comment: To avoid [SQL injection](https://xkcd.com/327/) (which may not work in Access but can if you later switch backends to Access app), consider parameterization as @Nathan_Sav. This is a good practice beyond VBA and beyond Access.

Answer (score 1):

#### Multiple Issues

1. **Type-mismatch** in WHERE clause:
   Your query (i.e. the WHERE clause) tries to compare a Number-column from database with a String-value (e.g. `WHERE numberField = '123'`). This will result in a runtime error [Type mismatch (Error 13)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/type-mismatch-error-13). See also [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885506/excel-vba-run-time-error-13-type-mismatch).
2. **Unsafe to use `+`** to concatenate Strings 
   When building the query you tried to concatenate the query-template with the number-parameter by a plus-sign. This works only when operating on numbers. See [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743823/concatenating-strings-in-vba)

#### Solution

1. remove single-quotes: you should compare the Number-column `NMT` with a number literal (e.g. `WHERE nmt = 123`)
2. use `&` to concatenate strings. This will also convert numbers to strings. Besides I explicitly used `CStr` function below.

```vb
Dim Con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim nmtNumber as Integer ' you named it x before

nmtNumber = me.textbox1.value
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE nmt = " & CStr(nmtNumber) ' removed single-quotes and used ampersand to concatenate with converted string
Con.Open "Provider= Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & U.Database01 & "\DB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False"
RS.Open strSQL, Con, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
```

#### Further improvement

I already extracted the SQL string (building) into a separate variable `strSQL` above.

Better would be to use *predefined/prepared* and *parameterized* queries:

- [`QueryDef` (DAO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao) where you can set the parameters (type-safe). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31059553/how-to-run-parameterized-query-from-vba-parameters-sourced-from-recordset).
- [`Command` (ADODB)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/querydef-object-dao) where you can set parameters (type-safe). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10352211/vba-ado-connection-and-query-parameters).

#### See also

- [What is ‘Run-time error ‘13’: Type mismatch’? And How Do You Fix It?](https://software-solutions-online.com/run-time-error-13-type-mismatch-fix/)
- [VBA Type Mismatch Error](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-type-mismatch/)

Comment: Thanks to [HunterX3: for setting the main focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536138/how-to-write-a-query-that-uses-a-number-as-parameter-and-number-type-field/59536495#comment105241902_59536138), [BigBen: for the concat-hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536138/how-to-write-a-query-that-uses-a-number-as-parameter-and-number-type-field/59536495#comment105241842_59536138),  [Nathan_Sav: for parameterized-queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536138/how-to-write-a-query-that-uses-a-number-as-parameter-and-number-type-field/59536495#comment105241897_59536138).